# Не видно другие view после WebView

Tags: android, android-layout, android-webview, android-view

В разметке есть `WebView` и следом за ним `Button`:

```
    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/lesson"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/type_background"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/lesson"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        android:text="Next lesson"/>
```

Если `WebView` занимает больше, чем размер экрана, то есть прокрутка самого `WebView`, но в конце `Button` не видно. Как сделать чтобы в конце прокрутки появлялась кнопка `Button`?

Comment: Реализация с Linear Layout в качестве родителя пойдёт?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В linearlayout их поставь, и скролл разреши